# Ubuntu set pulse audio sink for another user

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, pulseaudio

I'm running a targus dock (DOCK191USZ) with displaylink 5.4.1 and it periodically crashes, but automatically reloads.  Unfortunately when it does this, the default sound output is changed back to the line out instead of my bluetooth speakers.

I've written a script that checks for the bluetooth speakers and if connected, changes the audio output back to them, however if I try to run the script as a root user, it cannot see the pulse-audio daemon.

Even after setting the $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR var to the correct user PID, I still cant run pacmd commands as it complains I shouldnt be doing that.

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/1000) is not owned by us (uid 0), but by uid 1000! (This could e.g. happen if you try to connect to a non-root PulseAudio as a root user, over the native protocol. Don't do that.)
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
```

I'm also wanting to run this script as a systemd service so that I dont have to manage it, systemd will make sure it starts when the system starts, etc.  because of this, it runs as root.  I've tried running the systemd service as my local user, but it still cant see the pulseaudio daemon.

Ideas?  sure, it would be great if displaylink would fix their shit so it doesnt crash, but lets be real, ubuntu software support from manufacturers is still substandard on the best day.

script:

```
#!/bin/bash
logfile=/var/log/bluetooth/log
btsinkname=bluez_sink.60_F4_3A_71_89_E0.a2dp_sink
function btcheck {
  logprefix=$(echo "$(date +%b" "%d" "%H":"%M":"%S) $(hostname) btcheck [$(echo $BASHPID)]:")
  if [[ $(cat /sys/class/bluetooth/hci0:256/power/control 2>&1 | grep -Ec "^auto") -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "$logprefix connected" | tee -a $logfile
    export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
    pacmd set-default-sink $btsinkname 2>&1
  else
    echo "$logprefix not connected" | tee -a $logfile
  fi
  sleep 2s
  btcheck
}

btcheck
```

Answer (score 1):

I was soooo close.  just had to use my brain a little bit.

instead of

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
pacmd set-default-sink $btsinkname 2>&1
```

I had to combine them and use runuser

```
userid=$(runuser -l username -c "id -u")
runuser -l username -c "export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$userid && pacmd set-default-sink $btsinkname 2>&1"
```

Now with the systemd service running, my audio will be FORCED to stay connected to my bluetooth speakers.  Just have to wait a random period of time for the dock to crash now in order to see if my script works.

Comment: No need to export or use runuser twice, by the way. `runuser -l username -c "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u username) pacmd set-default-sink $btsinkname 2>&1"` is enough.